# How to make a traditional entity field excluded from revision?

Tags: 9

Is it possible to make an entity field excluded from revision? I want to avoid creating revision table for the field if possible. Otherwise, just excluding creating revisions is fine.

I tried to alter the field definition in code:

```
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'node' && isset($fields['field_my_field'])) {
    $fields['field_my_field']->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
    $fields['field_my_field']->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    $fields['field_my_field']->setRevisionable(FALSE);
  }
```

But got an errro that `setRevisionable`  does not exist. I looked further and found that drupal core has the following:

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function isRevisionable() {
    // All configurable fields are revisionable.
    return TRUE;
  }
```

Does this mean we can no longer alter this property on a field added via the UI?

Comment: 'Revisionable' is a property that can only be set on base fields, not on fields defined in configuration (aka through the UI). As far as I know it's not 'no longer', and this could never be done on fields defined in configuration.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294720/define-fields-created-through-the-ui-as-non-revisionable-on-a-revisionable-entit